# python how to write an update sql query?

Tags: python, sql, pypyodbc

I am trying to write an update query but I could not manage the string. My connections is ok.
My query is like this:

```
str='hello'
cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET message = '+str+' WHERE UserId=13')
```

This is giving me error: undefined column name 'hello'. I want to update message column as hello but it is getting it as a column name. In sql, when I write it as `UPDATE users SET message = 'hello' WHERE UserId=13` it works but I could not figured out how should I write my query like that in python. How should I write my query?

Comment: *Don't* concatenate strings to generate queries. What if `str` contained `3; DROP TABLE USERS; --` ? That's how SQL injection attacks happen. If you check the `cursor.execute` docs you'll see how to pass query parameters

Comment: Your Python script creates the following string: `UPDATE users SET message = hello WHERE UserId=13`, you need to quote `str` within the SQL statement.

Comment: [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) is back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET message="{}" WHERE UserId=13'.format("hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
str='hello'
cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET message = '" + str + "' WHERE UserId=13")
```